How do I hide contribution activity on a public Github repo?
I'm having a rather esoteric problem, of my own making.
I have a repository on my primary Github account which I intend to be available online and associated to a nom de plume. I recently created a second Github account to host this repository, so that I do not dox myself by associating my personal information present in my primary Github account to this repository.
I successfully transferred the repository to my second account. Unfortunately, the Insights tab still lists my primary account as the contributor to this repository.
I would like to keep the repository public, but hide my primary account's involvement so that there is no way to associate my primary account to this repository.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried reading the Github documentation, but the results I found were discussing how to make repositories private, which I do not want. I only want the contribution history to be private.
I also tried locking down privacy settings in my primary account, but the settings I was able to find were not sufficient to hide my primary account from the Insights.

When committing, make sure your user.email is set to the other account.

You can redo the commits with the new user.email setting, but that won't change any clones anyone else has already made.

For the contribution activity, GitHub doesn't care (much) about the account the repository is created with. It also doesn't care much about who pushed it.
Instead, it uses the username and E-Mail address associated with every commit. This is set via the user.name and user.email properties. If you don't want a commit to show up in your contribution activity, just set the name and E-Mail address for this repository on your computer
git config --local user.name 'Your display name for this repository here'
git config --local user.email 'the-mail-you-want-to-show@example.com'

However, note that this only applies for future commits made in this specific local repository. If you create another (local) repository or clone the repository again, you will need to configure that again.
On the other hand. if you create a commit with the web UI or create an issue/pull request or review one, GitHub will use the account you are logged in with.
Also note that if you push to the repository with your main account, this information will be accessible via the API. Specifically, you can use the URL https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPO_NAME/events and this includes push events like this (note that I omitted most of it):
[
  {
    "type": "PushEvent",
    "actor": {
      "id": USER_ID,
      "login": "USERNAME",
      "display_login": "USERNAME",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/USER_ID?"
    }
  }
]

